# In the Japanese original of "Bastard!!" what are the "Demon Gods" called?

Tags: manga, translation

What are [these guys](https://bastard.fandom.com/wiki/Demon_God) called in the original Japanese?

The article currently lacks information on the term used.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need in an [edit]. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please also take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OP just wants the original (untranslated) version of the word used to describe the demon gods, which I'm assuming will be some variant of 鬼神 (Kishin)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a variety of different scanslations ("demon god", "evil god", etc) but the original seems to be some variant of 'kishin'.

> [鬼神](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%AC%BC%E7%A5%9E) - literally “devil, devilish + god, spirit”

[image]
<sub><sup>**This image taken from Bastard!! #2**</sup></sub>